# How to toggle :hover effect?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle a hover effect that I have made with scss in laravel 5.

When I hover over the content in my case a cover image of a album, it works the effect.

But I wanted the effect to be active when a checkmark is filled.
I am now at a point that I can't add or toggle that hover effect. 
I tried adding a class but then the effect gets weird.

This is the codepenlink

```
**https://codepen.io/Edris89/pen/zJZEma**
```

This is the code that I used.
I putting it in for future use for others.

This is the HTML code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2" id="album-{{ $album->id }}">
                    <div class="content" id="content" >
                      <a id="overlay">
                        <div class="content-overlay">
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label class="checkbox_custom">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_custom_a" id="{{$album->id}}">
                                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362">
                        <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                          <h3 class="content-title"></h3>
                          <p class="content-text"></p>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
        </div>
  </div>


  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-4oV5EgaV02iISL2ban6c/RmotsABqE4yZxZLcYMAdG7FAPsyHYAPpywE9PJo+Khy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the scss code.

```
.container .title{
  color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content .content-overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  position: absolute;
  height: 99%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.content:hover .content-overlay{
  opacity: 0.6;
}



.content-image{
  width: 100%;
}

.content-details {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.content:hover .content-details{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content-details h3{
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content-details p{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

And for last the jquery code.

```
$( "input" ).change(function() {
            var $input = $( this );
            var checkboxState = $input.prop("checked");

            if(checkboxState == true){
                $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                    //console.log("Id: " + $input.attr("id") + " Value: " + $input.val());
                    //Cant figure out????
                });
            }

            if(checkboxState == false){
                $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                    //console.log("Id: " + $input.attr("id") + " Value: " + $input.val());

                });
            }
        }).change();
```

Comment: Hi Edrix89, Welcome to Stackoverflow. It's brilliant that you included the source code but I was wondering if you could do up a codepen or something similar? That would really help the people that will try and help you.

Comment: Thanks alot for the tip. I made the codepen and updated my message

Comment: I can't see the codepen link anywhere? If you can't edit the main post, just add in as a comment post

Comment: Yeah that was indeed the problem haha
this is the codepen link 
https://codepen.io/Edris89/pen/zJZEma

Comment: So the idea is that when that checkmark is marked. The same hover effect would be active. I am already checking for if the checkmark is checked in jquery. Just can't figure out how to toggle that hover state

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please take a minute and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Specifically you should include all relevant code in the question itself.  Otherwise this question becomes useless to future readers if your codepen becomes unavailable.

Comment: Aright gonna do that right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to add a new class that has the same CSS as the `:hover` effect.

Something like this where I added a `.checked` class.

```
.content:hover .content-overlay,
.content.checked .content-overlay {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Then in your Javascript, you need to toggle the class.

```
$("input")
  .change(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    var checkboxState = $input.prop("checked");

    if (checkboxState == true) {
      $(".content").addClass("checked");
      $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        //console.log("Id: " + $input.attr("id") + " Value: " + $input.val());
        //Cant figure out????
      });
    }

    if (checkboxState == false) {
      $(".content").removeClass("checked");
      $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        //console.log("Id: " + $input.attr("id") + " Value: " + $input.val());
      });
    }
  })
  .change();
```

[Here's an updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdmXpM)

Comment: Tried alot. And then this guy comes over just adding a class and stuff. Anndddd BAM its done :P Thanks alot man made me happy

Comment: A little problem. It's also updating other albums. No the specific chosen checkmark.

Comment: Yes, that's because your'e adding the class to all elements with .content class. You'll need to be more specific. I don't have all your HTML so it's hard to tell you how... but you'll probably need to use jQuery's .closest function. Something along the lines of $input.closest('.content').addClass('checked');

Comment: Aright thanks alot man! And for your time. Yeah I am sorry beginner over here:P
Gonna try it

Comment: We've all been there!

Comment: I updated the jQuery code. It now displays the hover effect for the specific chosen checkmark. Also with multiple albums.

However the problem is occuring when say 2 albums are selected but 1 album must be deselected. Then the hover effect is gone on all the albums. So it's deleting the class of all the albums.

Comment: The code.
$( "input" ).change(function() {
                var $input = $( this );
                var checkboxState = $input.prop("checked");

if(checkboxState == true){   $("input:checkbox:checked").closest(".content").addClass("checked");          $("input:checkbox:checked").closest(".content").addClass("details");
}
if(checkboxState == false){
$("input").closest(".content").removeClass("checked");
$("input").closest(".content").removeClass("details");
}
}).change();

Comment: To optimize, you can add all the classes at once since it's on the same element. $("input:checkbox:checked").closest(".content").addClass("checked details");

Comment: Same for removing the classes.
$("input:checkbox:checked").closest(".content").removeClass("checked details");

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE

@VVV I think I fixed it.

This is the jquery code.

```
            $( "input" ).change(function() {
            var $input = $( this );
            var checkboxState = $input.prop("checked");

            if(checkboxState == true){
                $(this).closest(".content").addClass("checked details");
            }

            if(checkboxState == false){
                $(this).closest(".content").removeClass("checked details");
            }
        }).change();
```

Comment: I got a bit tied down, but glad someone took up the mantle and helped you with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be a bit simpler.

Working on the same codepen as the accepted answer:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".content").toggleClass("checked");
});
```

If something else is supposed to happen:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".content").toggleClass("checked");
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {

    } else {

    }
});
```

Comment: That's actually pretty nice code. Gonna try it thanks alot.